# Excel sumifs with two values throwing an error

Tags: excel, sumifs

I am trying to get a sum of column C if A is `abc` or `cba` and B is `def`:

`=SUMIFS(C2:C51;A2:A51;{"abc","cba"};B2:B51;"def")`

But the formula is not valid, not sure where is my mistake since this was proposed in a quick google search.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is valid for me, but this might be an issue with your delimiter. Depending on your excel, windows or location settings you might need to use a comma `,` as a delimiter, instead of a semicolon `;`.

As for your formula, for completion I've done the same google search and ended up with [this reference](https://exceljet.net/formula/sumifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic). It seems your logic in the formula is correct apart from one crucial step, the `SUM(` wrapping around your formula. This means if your formula works, it will only take the first hit into account, but with the sum, it will count every entry where your logic is `True`. Syntax:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(C2:C51,A2:A51,{"abc","cba"},B2:B51,"def"))
```

Or semicolon delimited:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(C2:C51;A2:A51;{"abc";"cba"};B2:B51;"def"))
```

Since the {array} option does not seem to be working for you, I propose a workaround as follows:

```
=SUMIFS(C1:C15;A1:A15;"abc";B1:B15;"def")+SUMIFS(C1:C15;A1:A15;"cba";B1:B15;"def")
```

This is a more clunky function, but reaches the same result by splitting up the data in two `SUMIFS(` functions and adding the results together.

Comment: I am using semicolon-delimited, no idea why it does not work, when using `sumifs` with a single value it works fine, when I introduce `{ }` it does not recognize the next column range.

Comment: It doesn't seem an issue in my version, but have you tried delimiting `{"abc";"cba"}` with a semicolon as well? You don't seem to do that in your question. Other than that, I can't reproduce this issue, it might be that you're using an older version of excel that doesn't support this feature, but I have no way of testing that.

Comment: Yes I've tried using the second option, in this case only the `abc` is taking into place, the sum does not change if I use `{"abc";"cba"}.

Comment: Just for redundancy, do you have any rows where column A = "cba" and column B = "def" in your data? If the formula works but doesn't change, it might be that it doesn't find any hits in your data.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis Please see my revised answer with a proposed workaround. It's not pretty, but should work in your case. It will also tell you the answer to my earlier question, if you have the data your looking for to begin with.

Comment: I do have rows with the values and the formula gets accepted, although it does not seem to take the second value into calculation. Your workaround did work, thank you.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis If this answer helped, please, mark it as correct, so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Probably I would use @Plutian answer (actually I upvoted), but in case it might work for you, you can use SUMPRODUCT combined with DOUBLE UNARY to get exactly what you want.

> [DOUBLE UNARY](https://exceljet.net/glossary/double-unary)
>
> [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

I made a fake dataset like this:

[image]

As you can see, only the highlighted values meet your requirements ( if `A=abc OR cba AND B=def`)

My formula in E10 is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$7="abc")+--($A$2:$A$7="cba");--($B$2:$B$7="def");$C$2:$C$7)
```

This is how it works:

1. `($A$2:$A$7="abc")` will return an array of `True/False` values if condition is met.
2. That array, because it's inside a double unary operator `--( your range )`, will convert all `True/False` values into `1 or 0` values. Let's say it works like if you would have selected a range of cells that contains only 1 or 0. So this will return an array like `{1,0,1,0,1,0}` in this case
3. `--($A$2:$A$7="cba")` will do exactly the same than steps 1 or 2 again, but with your second option. It will return another array of values, in this case, `{0,1,0,1,0,1}`
4. `--($A$2:$A$7="abc")+--($A$2:$A$7="cba")` we are just summing up both arrays, so `{1,0,1,0,1,0}+{0,1,0,1,0,1}={1,1,1,1,1,1}`
5. `--($B$2:$B$7="def")` will do like steps 1 and 2 again with your third condition, and will return another array, now it will be `{1,0,1,0,0,1}`
6. The array obtained in step 5 then it's multiplied to array obtained in step 4, so we are doing `{1,1,1,1,1,1} * {1,0,1,0,0,1}={1,0,1,0,0,1}`
7. Now, that final array obtained in step 7 then it's multiplied by the **values** of cells `$C$2:$C$7`, so in this case is `{1,0,1,0,0,1} * {10,1,10,1,1,10} = {10,0,10,0,0,10}`
8. And final step, we sum up all values inside array obtained in last step, so we do `10+0+10+0+0+10=30`

I've explained every step to make sure everybody can understand, because SUMPRODUCT it's really an useful function if you know how to hanlde (I'm a noob, but I've seen real heroes here on SO using this function).

The advantage of using SUMPRODUCT instead of SUMIFS is that you can easily add more conditions to apply same range (case `--($A$2:$A$7="abc")+--($A$2:$A$7="cba")` or single condition to additional ranges (case `--($B$2:$B$7="def")`).

With normal SUMIFS probably you would have to add 1 extra complete SUMIF for each condition applied in same range.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is actually a very interesting technique, and I'm definitely going to play with it a bit. Do you have any sources for this I could look at by any chance? Upvoted either way.

Comment: Thanks @Plutian. I'm afraid I do not have any source, except the links provided, and a lot of SO questions, where the answer is SUMPRODUCT.